# MEAN + Passport: login failed, don't redirect just show an error in the same modal

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Just like in the question: how can I use Passport without redirecting user to the /signin or /home when he fails his authentication?

To login user has to click on "login" button, a modal will pop up, he fills the data. If he succeeds he is redirected to the homepage. But if he isn't I want to show him the flash message in the same modal without redirecting. It kinda works because if you fail to login and click "login" again the error message will be shown. But I don't want to force users to constantly click it to check what went wrong.

They should fail, see the error, fill in new data and click submit again.

home.server.route.js:

```
var user = require(__dirroot + '/app/controllers/user.server.controller.js')
var passport = require('passport')

module.exports = function(app) {
    var home = require(__dirroot + '/app/controllers/home.server.controller.js')
    app.get('/', home.render)

    app.route('/home/signin')
        .get(user.renderSignin)
        .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/',
            failureRedirect: '/',
            failureFlash: true
        }))
}
```

home.server.controller.js:

```
exports.render = function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'erpeg',
        messages: req.flash('error') || req.flash('info'),
        srvuser: req.user ? req.user : null,
        cltuser: JSON.stringify(req.user)
    })
}
```

home.ejs:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/foundation/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/foundation/css/foundation.css">
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="top-bar">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name">
                    <h1>
                        <a href="/">
                            <%= title %>
                        </a>
                    </h1>
                </li>
                <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>Menu</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <ul class="right">
                    <% if (srvuser) { %>
                        <% if(srvuser.rank == "administrator") { %>
                    <li>    
                        <a href="/admin"></a> 
                    </li>
                        <% } %>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/profile">
                            <%= srvuser.fullName %>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/signout">wyloguj</a>
                    </li>
                    <% } else { %>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/signup">rejestruj</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="signinModal">zaloguj</a>
                    </li>
                    <% } %>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </nav>

        <div id="signinModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="signinTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
            <% for (var i in messages) { %>
            <div data-alert class="alert-box warning">
                <p>
                    <%= messages[i] %>
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <h1 id="signinTitle">logowanie</h1>

        <form action="/home/signin", method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="nazwa użytkownia">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <input class="button expand" type="submit" value="zaloguj">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>

        <script src="lib/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/user/user.client.module.js"></script>
        <script src="/user/services/authentication.client.service.js"></script>
        <script src="/game/game.client.module.js"></script>
        <script src="/game/controllers/game.client.controller.js"></script>
        <script src="/game/services/game.client.service.js"></script>
        <script src="/game/config/game.client.route.js"></script>
        <script src="application.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: I had it working with separate pages but since I am changing my template engine from Jade to EJS I thought I will do it more elegantly (inside a modal). Any help?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is creating a JS script that will set that modal's visibility to true if the user is redirected from failed login attempt so it will automatically pop up after failure.

This method has some drawbacks though: 1. site needs to reload, 2. I don't really know how to check if the user is just performing a 200 request or he is redirected from a certain page.